# How to change the design of a menu strip?

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

When I create a new menu strip in Visual Studio it has an ugly design.
[image: Ugly design]
I tried to change the backgroundcolor and backgroundimage but it just got uglier than before.

How to change it to the "normal" Design?
[image: "normal" design]

Comment: Can you add pictures? and what do you mean but "normal" design ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `Rendermode` property of the `menuBar` object from `ManagedRenderMode` to `System` and you will get the old menu bar style.